# where to check the resource usage for azure SQL server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, database-performance, azure-sql-server, azure-elasticpool

I want to check the DTU usage or vcore usage pattern by azure SQL server. I need to get the usage data to convert the single database to an elastic pool.

Where on azure portal can I check the units consumed by the database?

Answer (score 0):

In the portal, all those values can be found under Metrics:

[image: SQL Database -> Metrics]

Once there, "Add metric", filter for "DTU" and select "DTU used".

[image]